# Impossible to mount USB hard drive. Filesystem not recognized?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have been using a raspberry PI since more than one year, with two USB 500GB IDE hard drives as a NAS/torrent box. Yesterday, one of the two hard drives started a repetitive rattling noise, and I could not read data from it through `sftp`.

I assumed it was broken, so I opened the box the raspberry and the hard drives were in, connected the first HD to my laptop using the IDE to USB adapter I had. Windows wasn't able to mount it. I really cannot remember which FS this HD is using, so I tried to mount it on a Debian Virtual Machine. The image below shows the error I get. I have no idea what it means, what I understand is that Debian does not recognize which FS the hard disk is using.

[image: screenshot]

This is the result of `fdisk -l` (only the part regarding the mentioned HDD):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 191411 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x17e817e7

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976773167   488385560   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mount the entire drive, not the formatted *parttion*.  Try mounting `/dev/sdb1`.

The parition type *Linux* suggests ext2, ext3, ext4.  NTFS would be `ntfs` (or `hpfs`)

Answer (score 1):

"Rattling noise" from the disk probably means the disk joined the big RAID in the sky. My condolences. The data on the disk was hopefully not critical...